# Can't compare pointer and int, C

Tags: c

I'm sending array to function `frekvens_of_array` and the size of it. Problems is it keeps telling me that I can't compare a `pointer` and an `int`. I try to insert new unique number into `frekvens` and add 1+ to hit every time number comes up in `alanyzed_array`

When I build this program, I'm getting errors and warnings like those below.

> `if(frekvens[j] != analyzed_arr[i])`
>   warning: comparision between pointer and integer [enable by default]
>
> `frekvens[j] = analyzed_arr[i];` error: incompatible types when assaigning to type 'int[1]' from type 'int'

```
int frekvens_of_array(int analyzed_arr[100], int array_size){
  int frekvens[100][1];
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int n = 0;
  int hit = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++){

    if(frekvens[j] != analyzed_arr[i]){
        frekvens[j] = analyzed_arr[i];

        for(n = 0; n < array_size; n++){
            if(frekvens[j] == analyzed_arr[n]){
                hit++;

            }

        }
        frekvens[j][0] = hit;
        j++;
    }

  }


  return 0;
}

int main(void){
int ange_tal_array[100];
int array_size = 100;

frekvens_of_array(ange_tal_array, array_size);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a two-dimensional 100*1 array instead of a one-dimensional array?

Comment: Can you please explain what this code is supposed to do? You're reading from `frekvens` without initializing any of its values.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I realized that I have misunderstandings of your code. The right way to solve your problem is to change the declaration of `frekvens` from:

```
int frekvens[100][1];
```

to:

```
int *frekvens[100];
```

to make it an array of pointers. And other parts of your code don't need to be modified.

Comment: Yeah i missed that point actaully, i wanted something to looke like {1 => {number of times it appear}, 2 => {number of times it appear}}

Answer (score 0):

```
int frekvens[100][1];
```

This is a 2D array of 100 rows and 1 columns. Quite frankly, having only one column doesn't make any sense; you should just turn it into a 1D array.

The issue is here:

```
if(frekvens[j] != analyzed_arr[i])
```

You're only indexing half of your 2D array. `frekvens[j]` is of type `int[1]`, so it's still an array. You're then comparing to an integer, which doesn't work.

The easiest fix would be to rewrite the line as `if(frekvens[j][0] != analyzed_arr[i])`, but the better solution would be to convert `frekvens` to a 1D array instead.

Comment: Yeah i missed that point actaully, i wanted something to looke like {1 => {number of times it appear}, 2 => {number of times it appear}}

Comment: Would an 3d array slove this?

Comment: @Nicco No. Make `frekvens` a `1D` array (`int frekvens[100];`) you'll then have to change `frekvens[j][0] = hit;` to `frekvens[j] = hit;` but then it should work.